# can we use alt fragment to describe multiple choices in uml's sequence diagram?

Tags: architecture, uml

i want to describe a menu with options in a sequence diagram for example : add member ,  delete member , modify member .
Can i use the alternative "alt" fragment to describe multiple choice instead of conditions ? thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure you can. The drawback with those fragments is, that they flood the screen quite fast and you end up in more confusion than clarification. Use fragments for rough overviews only, not for details. Once you start programming in SD you get lost.